# Is licensing information retained in some way in an swf file, compiled by Adobobe CS4 Professional?

Tags: flash, licensing, adobe, flash-cs4

I mean, is it theoretically possible to determine (based only on the content of the swf file) that the software which compiled the given swf was licensed trial or something else?

I guess Adobe would implement something like this to discourage using pirated software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. Your hacked copy of Flash CS4 is safe for now :P hehe.

Anyhow, if you look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf), you can see most of the information about what's in a .swf file. I mean, they could store something in metadata, but I just opened an empty .swf in a hex editor and I didn't see anything I thought could contain information about what version of Flash created the swf.

Comment: If you can only see most of the information, then you can't see ALL of the information, so you can't be sure. I'd like to trust your judgement that you didn't see suspicious things, but I fear Adobe have the means to trick you.